# Facebook webhook when user adds page event

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

We developed an application with which:

- Users login through Facebook
- the app determines the pages of which the user is administrator (manage_pages permission)
- the user selects one or more of his pages
- gets the events from those pages and imports them into our system

This already works.
What we want to achieve now is:

- To add a webhook in Facebook which alerts our system if the user adds an event into one of his pages
- Import those events automatically

On our testaccount for the app, we added the user_events permission.
We created a webhook which listens to user_events, but the url does not get called when the user adds an event on Facebook (neither when he adds a private or a page-event).
To test if it gets called we added a simple code on the url which is set:

```
$data = json_encode($_POST);
file_put_contents('file.txt', $data);
```

The moment we added the webhook on Facebook, the url got called correctly (also the verify token ecc was corret, it wrote "[]" into the file), but now it does not get called anymore.

What is missing is:

- The url has to be called when the user adds an event to one of his pages on Facebook (not if he adds a private event)
- We need to determine which of his pages he posted it into

I'm getting desperate, because I did not find much on this topic and am messing around with the API, but am quite stuck.